# console.log in GET route not printing to console

Tags: node.js, express, console

I have a simple `Node.js` app. There is a routing file, linked to in the main `server.js` file via

`var routes = require('./app/routes/index');`

It works fine.

However in the routes, I have a console output but it doesn't work - that is, it doesn't print anything to the console. The page I expect it to load works  perfectly in the browser, but the `console.log` does nothing - not in the browser console and not in the command prompt.

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.warn("Main Router");
    alert("Main Router");
    res.render('core/index', { title: 'Express' });
});
```

I'm starting the project with `npm start` in my windows command prompt. Everything is otherwise working.

Comment: You shouldn't expect the output from a `console.log` to give you anything in the browser. If you do it in Node, it will appear in your terminal. (that might apply for that `alert` as well) Are you sure that this app is not spawned as a separate child process? That might explain why it does not appear in the console. Do you have a more complete source for this?

Comment: Why would it spawn a separate child process? How would I know? I don't see any reason it would do that

Comment: You said it's a simple script, so that might not be the case. Unless you specifically did it or have it done by some module, then that will not be the issue.